# Mercurial path info - equivalent of SVN info

Tags: svn, mercurial, terminal

I want to get an output (for parsing) for HG repository similar to Subversions info command.
In other words - is there any way in Mercurial to get the following data for specific path and revision:

1. type (file/folder)
2. size (if type=file)
3. last edited changeset

Thank you all very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Mercurial doesn’t store directories, but some information can be had via `hg -v manifest`.
2. I don’t know anything specific, but you can use `hg cat` and `wc -c`.
3. Use `hg log -l1` on the file.

Comment: Also, it is possible to combine all three commands in nice hg alias

Comment: Actually, the answer to the last question is not very satisfactory, because it will also show changes from other branches/not reachable from the current head.